# run git hook before adding files to staging area

Tags: git, github, githooks

I have a project that uses prettier for formatting. I want my remote code repository to have files that have a consistent format. For this reason, I added a script in `package.json` file that will format the whole code base in one line of command(`npm run format`)

[image: package.json file]

This works! But the problem is that I may sometimes forget to format my code before `git push` to a remote repository. And I am not okay with cluttering my git history with unnecessary commits for the sake of formatting the code.

I resolved to automation and opting for **git hooks** that will format my code base with the command: `npm run format` every time I add file(s) to the staging area.
But I seem not to find a git hook for my use case.

Is there a hook that can run before staging files?

Comment: no such git hook exists, though the standard place to solve this is during the `pre-commit` hook or the `pre-push` hook

Comment: Thanks @AnthonySottile though using the hooks you have mentioned will require me to add again add files to the staging area since it will format before committing and modified files are left uncommitted

Answer (score 1):

There is no such Git hook.  However, you have two options if you want to handle formatting.

One is to use a `pre-commit` hook to check your files before committing.  This won't prevent you from adding them, but it will prevent you from committing them.  However, `pre-commit` hooks can be very burdensome if you use some advanced workflows which use many temporary and fixup commits.

Another option is to use a clean filter.  You can create a pattern in your `.git/info/attributes` file like this:

```
src/**/*.js filter=prettier
```

and then you can add the following to `.git/config`:

```
[filter "prettier"]
smudge = cat
clean = "YOUR-PRETTIER-COMMAND-HERE"
```

You'd replace `YOUR-PRETTIER-COMMAND-HERE` with a command that reads the file from standard input and writes it in an appropriate format to standard output.  (It is not possible to use a program that formats in place on the file system.)  That will automatically run JavaScript files through that filter when running `git add` and store them in the repository with proper formatting.